# LFS v7.2 libc-2.16 error while make

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, glibc, linux-from-scratch

While glibc-2.16 make following error occurred:

glibc-build/math/s_modff.os.dt -MT

/media/vaibhav/sources/glibc-build/math/s_modff.os

../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/s_isnanf.c:37:1: error: '**EI**_isnanf'

aliased to external symbol '**GI**_isnanf' make[2]: ***

[/media/vaibhav/sources/glibc-build/math/s_isnanf.os] Error 1 make[2]:

*** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make[2]: Leaving directory

`/media/vaibhav/sources/glibc-2.16.0/math' make[1]: ***

[math/subdir_lib] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory

`/media/vaibhav/sources/glibc-2.16.0' make: *** [all] Error 2

Please help me.

Comment: You should copy and paste the original messages from the compiler again because it looks like you've got lines all scrunched up.  I think the messages in the style of `make[2]` would normally start a new line of output.  Indent the text by 4 spaces; or use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the highlighted material by 4 spaces.  Your problem may be that glibc 2.16 was released in June 2012 and does things that your compiler does not approve of. Maybe you should try glibc 2.17 (December 2012)?  Or try using the version of GCC that was current when glibc 2.16 was released.

Comment: I will try to build glibc-2.17. Hope it works.